# Is this normal behavior for UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I notice when I set MessageTableViewCell **accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton**  and I tab on the "arrow button" itself, the pop menu that is declared on **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** don't show up??!!! it works fine if I tabbed on the other area of cell, except on the "arrow button" itself,

However, if I used **UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator** cell accessory type instead, it works fine, even if I tabbed on the arrow itself.

I wonder if this normal behavior, a bug, or I did something wrong.

I prefer **UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton** because in my opinion its more clear when you want to get attention of user.

```
    - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    {
        static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"MessageCellIdentifier";

        MessageTableViewCell* cell = (MessageTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = /*[*/[[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] /*autorelease]*/;

        }
        CastNearAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CastNearAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


        Message* message = [appDelegate.dataModel messageWithID: indexPath.row];

        if (!message.isSentByUser)
        {
            cell.accessoryType =/*UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton; */UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        message.bubbleSize = [SpeechBubbleView sizeForText:message.text];

        [cell setMessage:message];

        return cell;
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




       UIActionSheet  *popupQueryOptions = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"Options for Blocking and Spam Reporting"
                                          delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Block Sender"
                                          otherButtonTitles:/*@"Block Sender",*/
                                          @"Inappropriate Content",
                                          /*@"Tell a Friend via Facebook",
                                           @"Tell a Friend via Twitter",*/
                                          nil];

        popupQueryOptions.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

        [popupQueryOptions showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];


}
```

Comment: @Paul.s is correct. In future, don't forget to check out the docs first - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used for different things. The indicator is just an indicator whereas the button allows you to have a different action e.g. acting like a button.

`UITableView` has two possible methods that it will call on it's delegate when the cell is tapped.

When the row itself is tapped the following is called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When you tap on the accessory then the tableView calls

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can also wire these up independently in Interface Builder. So this behaviour is quite deliberate.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the disclosure button, the delegate method `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` is called instead of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

The disclosure button is usually used for some kind of secondary action of a cell, e.g. in the Wifi settings, it shows options for a network, while tapping the entire cell connects to it.